# Need to filter data date wise

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, nest

I have some query result data like..

```
"results": [
    {
        "activityId": "7",
        "universityId": "23",
        "studentId": "25",
        "content": "Add course in cart",
        "activityType": "chat",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-10T22:25:29.798Z"
    },
    {
        "activityId": "6",
        "universityId": "17",
        "studentId": "25",
        "content": "Add course in cart",
        "activityType": "chat",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-09T23:48:23.554Z"
    },
    {
        "activityId": "5",
        "universityId": "17",
        "studentId": "25",
        "content": "Add course in cart",
        "activityType": "chat",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-08T23:48:21.841Z"
    }
]
```

Now I need to filter the data like:

```
[
  {
    title: 2022-04-10 (here createdAt value),
    value: {
            "activityId": "5",
            "universityId": "17",
            "studentId": "25",
            "content": "Add course in cart",
            "activityType": "chat"
      }
  }
]
```

I am using nestJS.

```
const allActivity = [];
      Promise.all(
        results.map((value) => {
          if (allActivity.length <= 0) {
            const obj = {
              title: value.createdAt,
              values: value,
            };
            allActivity.push(obj);
          }
        }),
      );
```

I just need to filter the data with this format or just need to complete my function that I have written below.

Comment: You haven't clearly said which condition you need for the filter. Without your condition, everything will be assumed and we cannot help to have straightforward answers

Comment: @NickVu Actually I have some data at first  I have shown, I have to format the data createdAt entity wise. formatted table example is 2nd code.

Comment: If they have the same date, you will group them under `value`?

Comment: I have to filter the data like this.. https://ibb.co/Cb0FwN7 @NickVu

Comment: I tried to gather your ideas for the code answer, hopefully it's good enough for your case

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
select * from data where createdAt like '2022-04-10%'
```

The returned table with this query will be in the same format that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to group by `createdAt` by trimming time.

```js
const results = [{activityId:"6",universityId:"17",studentId:"25",content:"Add course in cart",activityType:"chat",createdAt:"2022-04-09T23:48:23.554Z"},{activityId:"5",universityId:"17",studentId:"25",content:"Add course in cart",activityType:"chat",createdAt:"2022-04-08T23:48:21.841Z"},{activityId:"9",universityId:"11",studentId:"26",content:"Add course in cart",activityType:"chat",createdAt:"2022-04-08T23:48:21.841Z"}];
const map = new Map();

for (const ele of results) {
  const date = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', {
    dateStyle: 'medium',
  }).format(new Date(ele.createdAt));
  if (map.has(date)) {
    map.set(date, [ele, ...map.get(date)]);
    continue;
  }
  map.set(date, [ele]);
}

const output = Object.fromEntries(map.entries());

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this implementation with `reduce`

```js
const results = [{
    "activityId": "7",
    "universityId": "23",
    "studentId": "25",
    "content": "Add course in cart",
    "activityType": "chat",
    "createdAt": "2022-04-10T22:25:29.798Z"
  },
  {
    "activityId": "6",
    "universityId": "17",
    "studentId": "25",
    "content": "Add course in cart",
    "activityType": "chat",
    "createdAt": "2022-04-09T23:48:23.554Z"
  },
  {
    "activityId": "5",
    "universityId": "17",
    "studentId": "25",
    "content": "Add course in cart",
    "activityType": "chat",
    "createdAt": "2022-04-08T23:48:21.841Z"
  }, {
    "activityId": "8",
    "universityId": "17",
    "studentId": "25",
    "content": "New testing",
    "activityType": "chat",
    "createdAt": "2022-04-08T23:48:21.841Z"
  }
]

//format your date from `2022-04-08T23:48:21.841Z` to `2022-04-08`
const formatDate = (date) => date.split('T')[0]

const finalResult = results
  .reduce((finalList, item) => {
    const currentItemFormattedDate = formatDate(item.createdAt)
    const foundItem = finalList.find(addedItem => formatDate(addedItem.title) === currentItemFormattedDate)
    //if it's not in the final list, we need to create a new title
    if (!foundItem) {
      finalList.push({
        title: currentItemFormattedDate,
        value: [{
          ...item
        }]
      })
    } else {
      //if it's in the final list, we just need to push value
      foundItem.value.push({
        ...item
      })
    }
    return finalList
  }, [])

console.log(finalResult)
```

The easier way with [`groupBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/groupBy), but instead of `title`, I'm using keys for date representation

```js
const results = [{
    "activityId": "7",
    "universityId": "23",
    "studentId": "25",
    "content": "Add course in cart",
    "activityType": "chat",
    "createdAt": "2022-04-10T22:25:29.798Z"
  },
  {
    "activityId": "6",
    "universityId": "17",
    "studentId": "25",
    "content": "Add course in cart",
    "activityType": "chat",
    "createdAt": "2022-04-09T23:48:23.554Z"
  },
  {
    "activityId": "5",
    "universityId": "17",
    "studentId": "25",
    "content": "Add course in cart",
    "activityType": "chat",
    "createdAt": "2022-04-08T23:48:21.841Z"
  }, {
    "activityId": "8",
    "universityId": "17",
    "studentId": "25",
    "content": "New testing",
    "activityType": "chat",
    "createdAt": "2022-04-08T23:48:21.841Z"
  }
]

const formatDate = (date) => date.split('T')[0]

//groupBy is not fully supported for all browsers, so I use vanilla Javascript for it
const groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};

const finalResult = groupBy(results.map(item => ({...item, createdAt: formatDate(item.createdAt)})), "createdAt")

console.log(finalResult)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this map function

```js
const results = [{
    "activityId": "7",
    "universityId": "23",
    "studentId": "25",
    "content": "Add course in cart",
    "activityType": "chat",
    "createdAt": "2022-04-10T22:25:29.798Z"
  },
  {
    "activityId": "6",
    "universityId": "17",
    "studentId": "25",
    "content": "Add course in cart",
    "activityType": "chat",
    "createdAt": "2022-04-09T23:48:23.554Z"
  },
  {
    "activityId": "5",
    "universityId": "17",
    "studentId": "25",
    "content": "Add course in cart",
    "activityType": "chat",
    "createdAt": "2022-04-08T23:48:21.841Z"
  }
]

const mapped = results.map(({
  createdAt,
  ...value
}) => {
  return {
    title: createdAt.split('T')[0],
    value
  }
})

console.log(mapped)
```

Comment: I have console mapped getting this data.
Promise {
  <pending>,
  [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 58518,
  [Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol)]: 58481,
  [Symbol(destroyed)]: { destroyed: false }
} this is maped

Comment: @Rabbani_ you have to wait until you got the response from your ajax call so put this map inside a then or after an await in your async function